# Compare a variable with a text

Tags: ansible

I can't compare the variable with the text
From children inventory I pass the variable
I need to stop the execution of the playbook if the variable is not equal to the passed text
Simple comparisons don't work, I tried different options, one of them is like this

```
- name: Stop the executing
  fail:
    msg: MY_TEXT
  when: ( {{ project }} != "tmp1" ) or ( {{ project }} != "tmp2" )
```

How to compare a variable with a text correctly?

Comment: `when` and all its derivate **should never be templated**: [_The `when` clause is a raw Jinja2 expression without double curly braces_](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#basic-conditionals-with-when)

Comment: You should also rethink your logic: `'a' != 'a' or 'a' != 'b'` will always be true, you want an **and** here: `'a' != 'a' and 'a' != 'b'`

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to do it - I think...

```
- name: Stop the executing
  fail:
    msg: MY_TEXT
  when: 
    project not in ['tmp1', 'tmp2']
```